# internal server error 500 with jquery.min.js

Tags: php, jquery

I am a novice to PHP. Now I am building a simple login-logout system. While trying to log in the system, I got the Internal Server Error with jquery.min.js:4. Here is my code:
Index:

```
<!-- Login Form -->
<form method="post" id="loginForm">
<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#loginHeading" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="loginHeading">Login Form</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="loginMessage"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pass">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox" >
              <div class="pull-left" style="padding-left:20px">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#forgetPass" data-toggle="modal">Forget password?</a>
              </div>
              <label class="pull-right" style="padding-right:20px"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value=""> Remember me</label>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp">Register</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn myBtn">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
 $("#loginForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dataPost= $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
      url: '4-logIn.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: dataPost,
      success:function(data){
        if (data == "success") {
          window.location("mainPageLogin.php");
        }
        else {
          $("#loginMessage").html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function(data){
        $('#loginMessage').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><h5>Error in connection with loginForm</h5></div>');
      }
    });
  });
```

4-login.php:
``

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include '0-connection.php';

  $error='';

  $email=filter_var($_POST["email"],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $pass=filter_var($_POST["pass"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  // Query
  $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$email);
  $pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$pass);
  $pass=hash('sha256',$pass);

  $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass' AND activation='activated'";
  $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  if (!$result) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error running the query to take user login</div>";
    exit;
  }
  $count= mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($count !== 1) {
    $error="<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>ERROR:</strong> Wrong username or password. Please try again or Do you want to <a href='#' data-dismiss='modal' data-target='#signUp' data-toggle='modal'>Sign up</a></div>";
    echo $error;
  }
  else {
    // Set session
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
    $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
    // Check remember me Box
    if (empty($_POST['remember'])) {
      echo "success";
    }
    else {

    }

  }
  ?>
```

This is my error:
[demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua6QB.png)
[web response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNd6V.png)

Please be more specific in your answer because I am very new in programming. Thanks for reading.

Comment: share `4-logIn.php` also ?

Comment: I think it's unnecessary because I got the error right in the script, which means that it cannot connect to 4-login.php My 4-login.php is still incomplete, I want to try if my system can work perfectly by inputting the wrong password intentionally. As far as I read, this is the server error, it is not my code problem. Anyway, I will update it.

Comment: just try with `echo "someting".` in your .php file and comment rest of code for now ? and let us know ?

Comment: run 4-logIn.php only. you will get exactly where the error is. or inspect the document and click console. the error should be there. Error 500 is a server error

Comment: @HaVan straight from **[the horses mouth](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1)** , a 500 is `The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.`. period. Dont trust what you see in a browser, get real information. So, it did not mean `you could not open whatever.php`, it means that when trying to interpreting `whatever.php` some nasty condition caused php to die unexpectedly. period. It could could happen on the 1000'th line of code.

Comment: Ok thanks, guys. I finally can solve my problems.

Comment: Just a tip: Build the PHP code first using a normal login form. You can add JavaScript later. That way you only have to debug one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Error in 4-logIn.php, `if (!result) {` must be changed as `if (!$result) {`